# Summing numbers using Threads

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

The code gives me an error..what iam i doing wrong here

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import datetime

MAX_NUM = 10000
NUMPROCS = 1



# THREADING
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

start_time = datetime.now() 

def sum_range(start,stop,out_q):
i = start
counter = 0
while i < stop:
counter += i
i += 1
out_q.put(counter)

mysums = Queue()
mybounds = [1+i for i in range(0,MAX_NUM+1,int(MAX_NUM/NUMPROCS))]
myprocs = []

for i in range(NUMPROCS):
p = Process(target=sum_range, args=(mybounds[i],mybounds[i+1],mysums))
p.start()
myprocs.append(p)

mytotal = 0
for i in range(NUMPROCS):
mytotal += mysums.get()

for i in range(NUMPROCS):
   myprocs[i].join()
print(mytotal)
end_time =datetime.now()
print('Time taken : {}'. format(end_time-start_time))
```

was trying to make make a thread code that sums numbers.it gives me the error below
  if **name** == '**main**':
                freeze_support()
                ...

```
    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your code?  Also, your code doesn't have the statement `if name == '__main__': ...`.  Is the code you show the actual code that you are running?

Comment: @Warren I presume the OP may be getting this error when compiling their program with cx freeze. That's just a guess though